# Extract version-specific upgrade notice from readme text

Tags: php, regex, version, text-extraction, readme

I am currently writing a PHP function which should help me to extract an upgrade notice from a given readme text.

This is my source text:

```
Some stuff before this notice like a changelog with versioning and explanation text.

== Upgrade Notice ==

= 1.3.0 =

When using Master Pro, 1.3.0 is the new minimal required version!

= 1.1.0 =

When using Master Pro, 1.1.0 is the new minimal required version!

= 1.0.0 =

No upgrade - just install :)

[See changelog for all versions](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/master-pro/trunk/CHANGELOG.md).
```

This is the function:

```
/**
 * Parse update notice from readme file
 *
 * @param string $content
 * @param string $new_version
 *
 * @return void
 */
private function parse_update_notice( string $content, string $new_version ) {
    $regexp  = '~==\s*Upgrade Notice\s*==\s*(.*?=+\s*' . preg_quote( $new_version ) . '\s*=+\s*(.*?)(?=^=+\s*\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s*=+|$))~ms';

    if ( preg_match( $regexp, $content, $matches ) ) {
        $version = trim( $matches[1] );
        $notices = (array) preg_split( '~[\r\n]+~', trim( $matches[2] ) );

        error_log( $version );
        error_log( print_r( $notices, true ) );
    }
}
```

I am currently stuck at my RegEx. I'm not really getting it to work. This was my initial idea:

1. Only search after `== Upgrade Notice ==`
2. Check if we have a version matching `$new_version`
3. Get the matched version between the `= x.x.x =` as match 1 e.g. `1.1.0`
4. Get the content after the version as match 2 but stopping after an empty new line. The upgrade notice can go over multiple lines but without an empty new line.

Comment: Instead of using `|$` try using `|\z`

Comment: This will not use the `s` modifier and stop when encountering an empty line `^==\h*Upgrade Notice\h*==\R\s*^=\h*(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\h*=\R\s*^((?:\h*\S.*(?:\R\h*\S.*)*)+)` https://regex101.com/r/dsgR8p/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird will this work with a specific version passed to the RegEx as well? So if I want to output the 2nd or 3rd version notice?

Comment: If you want to be able to determine which part you want, you might use a quantifier and change the amount of occurrences you want to skip before you want to capture. So this will give you the first https://regex101.com/r/lBQIg3/1 and this will give you the second etc...https://regex101.com/r/oVCcez/1

Comment: @The can these comments be removed now?

Comment: @MrJ all of your requirements must be clearly detailed in the question body.  Additional commented requirements will lead to answers satisfying different requirements.

Comment: @MrJ `preg_split()` only returns array-type data; there is no need to explicitly cast the return data as an array.  Splitting on `[\r\n]+` is more elegantly written as `\R+`.

Comment: I also [tried this (regex101 demo)](https://regex101.com/r/nS2GvN/1) but not sure if on the right track!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the first part after "Upgrade Notice", matching only the first following block with non empty lines, you can omit the `s` flag to have the dot match a newline and capture matching all following lines that contain at least a single non whitespace character.

```
^==\h*Upgrade Notice\h*==\R\s*^=\h*(1\.3\.0)\h*=\R\s*^((?:\h*\S.*(?:\R\h*\S.*)*)+)
```

The line in PHP:

```
$regexp = '~^==\h*Upgrade Notice\h*==\R\s*^=\h*(' . preg_quote( $new_version ) . ')\h*=\R\s*^((?:\h*\S.*(?:\R\h*\S.*)*)+)~m';
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lBQIg3/1)

---

If you want to be able to determine which occurrence after matching "Upgrade Notice", you can use a quantifier to skip the amount of occurrences that start with the version pattern:

```
^==\h*Upgrade Notice\h*==(?:(?:\R(?!=\h*\d+\.\d+\.\d+\h*=$).*)*\R=\h*(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\h*=$\s*){2}(^\h*\S.*(?:\R\h*\S.*)+)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `==\h*Upgrade Notice\h*==` The starting pattern, where `\h*` match optional horizontal whitespace characters
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:\R(?!=\h*\d+\.\d+\.\d+\h*=$).*)*` Match all lines that do not start with a version pattern
  - `\R=\h*` Match a newline and `=` followed by horizontal whitespace characters
  - `(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match the version
  - `\h*=$\s*` Match horizontal whitespace characters, `=` and assert the end of the string and match optional whitespace characters
- `){2}` Use a quantifier (in this case `{2}`) to match n times a version pattern
- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?:\h*\S.*(?:\R\h*\S.*)*)+` Match 1 or more lines that contain at least a single non whitespace character
- `)` Close the group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xwVNPp/1)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do everything with a regex. Just use a regex for the version detection. Here's a simplified version:

Demo: https://3v4l.org/aMdXF

```
$versions = [];
$currentVersion = '';
$ignore = true;
foreach(explode("\n", $md) as $line) {
    if (str_starts_with($line, '== Upgrade Notice ==')) {
        $ignore = false;
        continue;
    }

    if (preg_match('/^= ([0-9.]+) =/', $line, $matches)) {
        $currentVersion = $matches[1];
        continue;
    }

    if (true === $ignore || '' === $currentVersion) {
        continue;
    }

    $versions[$currentVersion][] = $line;
}
```

Comment: I think this is very risky since the readme file contains a lot of more data before, also some other version strings which are not relevant for the upgrade notice. Thats why I want to use a RegEx to only search after the == Upgrade Notice ==.

Comment: @Mr.Jo Then just ignore everything before. See answer and Demo updated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution not based on regex but good old `strpos()`:

```
function getNotice($readme, $version)
{
    $txt = str_replace("\r", '', $readme);
    $p1 = strpos($txt, "== Upgrade Notice ==");
    if($p1 !== false)
    {
        $ver = "= $version =";
        $p2 = strpos($txt, $ver, $p1);
        if($p2 !== false)
        {
            $p2 += strlen($ver) + 2;
            $p3 = strpos($txt, "\n\n", $p2);
            if($p3 !== false)
                return substr($txt, $p2, $p3 - $p2);
            else
                return substr($txt, $p2);
        }
    }
    return '';
}

$readme = <<<README
Some stuff before this notice which is not relevant.

== Upgrade Notice ==

= 1.3.0 =

When using Master Pro, 1.3.0 is the new minimal required version!
Additional line.

= 1.1.0 =

When using Master Pro, 1.1.0 is the new minimal required version!

= 1.0.0 =

No upgrade - just install :)

[See changelog for all versions](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/master-pro/trunk/CHANGELOG.md).
README;

echo getNotice($readme, '1.3.0');
```

Output:

```
When using Master Pro, 1.3.0 is the new minimal required version!
Additional line.
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Olivier! It would be interesting to know if the RegEx or the strpos() is faster. I also like shingo's approach but it's currently ignoring any additional line.

Comment: @Mr.Jo `strpos()` is faster than a regex (expecially a complex regex).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Just checked your code. When I pass a version which is not given like 0.1.0, it's printing a part from the beginning of the file. Not sure if it should work like this?

Comment: These variable names could be more indicative.  As a fringe consideration, if someone sneaks a multibyte character into the text, the byte counts may skew the result.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it's just a mistake in the position of your parentheses:

```
'~==\s*Upgrade Notice\s*==\s*.*?=+\s*(' . preg_quote( $new_version ) .
  ')\s*=+\s*(.*?)(?=^=+\s*\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s*=+|^\s*?$)~ms'
```

https://3v4l.org/WY3aE

Comment: Thanks a lot! How do I need to modify the RegEx to also include multiple lines? Like when there is a line break inside the notice without an empty line break in between?

Comment: You can use `^\s*?$` to replace the last `$` to match a blank line.

Comment: @MrJ your [mcve] should contain multiline notices for clarity.